# HTML - Make multiple td linkable

Tags: html

So I have researched making tr's and td's linkable and have been using the onclick method for the entire row. Is there a way to make 2 td's link to one page and 2 link to another?

```js
function x() {
  window.location.href = 'x.com';
}

function y() {
  window.location.href = 'y.com';
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.x:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.y:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="x" onclick="javascript:x"></td>
    <!--I want these 2 td to be the same link-->
    <td class="x" onclick="javascript:x"></td>

    <td class="y" onclick="javascript:y"></td>
    <!--and this one be a different link-->
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="x" colspan="2" onclick="javascript:x"></td>
    <!--so it looks like this but 2 cells are enclosed in the same link-->

    <td class="y" onclick="javascript:x"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you elaborate "*so it looks like this but 2 cells are enclosed in the same link*"

Comment: use a class and js?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa Sure, so right now I have each td with onlick="blah" in them. The 1st 2 cells go to x.com and the 3rd one goes to y.com. Each cell is a separate link. I want the first 2 cells that go to x.com to be in the same link. So you hover over the 1st cell and that plus the 2nd cell will be highlighted. Think about it this way, if each td was a div, I want an <a> to be around the 1st 2 cells, but that is not possible.

Comment: so does this work. if you click on elements with `class="x"`, redirect to `x.com`. If clicked on elements with `class="y"`, redirect to `y.com` ? Need JS for this though

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa Ya i forgot to add the js, I have edited my answer though.

Comment: Is `onclick="javascript:"` the only way you want? Currently the code is redundant and not efficient. I mean using `$('.x').on('click'` would mean writing only once and it will work for both the table cells

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa No i'm open to any other way, but that's just what I have now. I just need two td in the same link so you can hover over one and both background colors are changed

Comment: In that case, for the JS what @Obsidian mentioned below is a better version of your code(assuming your using jquery). Having the hover effect is easy, you could maybe **remove the border between the two cells** to create the illusion that its one

Comment: I do not know what sass or less is, so no. I just want both td to be in the same link. I may look at using divs instead of a table, but that may complicate my php that I need this for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LINK HOVER EFFECTS BY CLASS**

```js
 $('.x').hover(function () {
    $('.x').toggleClass('active');
 });
```

```css
table{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid;
}
td{
  border:1px solid;
}
.x:hover,
.active{
  background-color:red;
}
.y:hover{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="x"></td> <!--I want these 2 td to be the same link-->
    <td class="x"></td>

    <td class="y"></td> <!--and this one be a different link-->
  </tr>
</table>
```

**WITH PURE CSS (IF CLASS IS SIBLING)**

```css
table{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid;
}
td{
  border:1px solid;
}
.x:hover,
.x:hover ~ .x{
  background-color:red;
}
.y:hover{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="x"></td> <!--I want these 2 td to be the same link-->
    <td class="x"></td>

    <td class="y"></td> <!--and this one be a different link-->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not what I wanted. I see where I confused you though, I have the onclick functions in my code but I want an onclick that surrounds 2 of my table cells

Comment: may be it would be much better if you show us your `onclick` function

Comment: Are you saying you want to wrap the td with an anchor? And why do you need this type of functionality?

Comment: @Obsidian Yes I want to wrap 2 td with the anchor, but that's not possible so I need a different way to do it. I am making a php table where one cell is linked to do a different function than the other cells

Comment: And what is wrong with the colspan with the anchor inside? This would be easy if the page wasn't a table. Is the table layout essential?

Comment: @Obsidian Yes I need the table layout for my php, I'm not using colspan that was just an example of what I want to happen, the 2 td are both highlighted when one is hovered over

Comment: @xyz making 2 td linkable? I'm kind of new to html/css but can't this be done with `n-th:child` in CSS? Or do you specifically want a javascript way?

Comment: is the cell always next to it or do we need to search for all cells with class? See my edits above. I think this is what you mean

Comment: @Obsidian The cell is always next to it

Comment: Ok I see what you did, I was just over complicating my problem. Thanks for the answer

Comment: There is a next sibling selector in css without the need for javascript. See edits above.